# TensorFlow dataset with multi-dimensional Tensors from a CSV file

Tags: tensorflow, tensor, tensorflow-datasets

Is there a way, and if yes, what it is, to load a TensorFlow dataset with multi-dimensional feature Tensor from a CSV (or other format input) file?

For example, my CSV input looks like the following:

```
f1,  f2,  f3,                      label
0.1, 0.2, 0.1;0.2;0.3;1.1;1.2;1.3, 1
0.2, 0.3, 0.2;0.3;0.4;1.2;1.3;1.4, 0
0.3, 0.4, 0.3;0.4;0.5;1.3;1.4;1.5, 1
```

I'd like load a dataset from such file, e.g.

```
import tensorflow as tf

frames_csv_ds = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
    'input.csv',
    header=False,
    column_names=['f1','f2','f3','label'],
    batch_size=5,
    label_name='label',
    num_epochs=1,
    ignore_errors=True,)

for batch, label in frames_csv_ds.take(1):
  for key, value in batch.items():
    print(f"{key:20s}: {value}")
  print()
  print(f"{'label':20s}: {label}")
```

To get the batch as:

```
f1 : [0.1   0.2   0.3  ]
f2 : [0.2   0.3   0.4  ]
f3 : [ [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3], [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]], [[0.2, 0.3, 0.4], [1.2, 1.3, 1.4]], [[0.3, 0.4, 0.5], [1.3, 1.4, 1.5]] ]
label : [1, 0, 1]
```

The snippet above is incomplete and doesn't work. Is there away to get the dataset in the illustrated form? If yes, can this be done for arrays of dimensions varying across the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do this by customizing some Tensorflow Functions

```
import tensorflow as tf

file_path = "data.csv"
dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_path).skip(1)

def parse_csv_line(line):
  # Split the line into a list of strings
  fields = tf.io.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=[[""]] * 4)
  
  f1 = tf.strings.to_number(fields[0], tf.float32)
  f2 = tf.strings.to_number(fields[1], tf.float32)
  f3 = tf.strings.to_number(tf.strings.split(fields[2], ";"), tf.float32)
  label = tf.strings.to_number(fields[3], tf.int32)
  
  return {"f1": f1, "f2": f2, "f3": f3, "label": label}

dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv_line).batch(5)
```

```
next(iter(dataset.take(1)))
```

```
{'f1': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3], dtype=float32)>,
 'f2': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.2, 0.3, 0.4], dtype=float32)>,
 'f3': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 6), dtype=float32, numpy=
 array([[0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3],
        [0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
        [0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5]], dtype=float32)>,
 'label': <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=int32, numpy=array([1, 0, 1], dtype=int32)>}
```

Comment: Thank you! But doesn’t this method load everything into memory? My dataset is huge, that wouldn’t work in my case.

Comment: No, the `tf.data.TextLineDataset` method loads the data from the CSV file in a lazy manner, meaning that it only loads the data as it is needed, rather than loading everything into memory all at once. This allows you to work with very large datasets that would not fit into memory, and it also allows you to process the data in a more efficient manner by only loading the data that is needed at each step.

Comment: the other thing is this method is member of `tf.data.Dataset` class which provides you the flexible environment in which you can set your `batch-size` and `shuffle` and other methods, it processes all the data in the parallel, you can use `prefetch` method, which is more efficient for huge datasets.

Comment: Read the documentation also.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TextLineDataset

Answer (score 1):

This method `def get_window_data(df: pd.DataFrame, target: pd.Series, window_size: int, todict=False):` receives a df with ***N columns***, and ***pd.Series*** with the value of the Ground True
Example: *df from csv (2d array) of 15596 rows by 76 columns with a Ground True of (15596, 3):*

```py
 LOG Shapes: X_train: (15596, 76) y_train: (15596, 3) index_train: (15596,)
```

Returns Multidimensional, ***3d Array*** (with time windows), for ***a*** reference GT ***N previous time rows***.
the time windows are composed of the previous 48 rows, in this example

Example: *3d array of 15596 rows, in time windows of 48, by 76 columns with a Ground True of (15596 , 3)*

```py
 LOG Shapes: X_train: (15596, 48, 76) y_train: (15596, 3) index_train: (15596,)
```

```py
def get_window_data(df: pd.DataFrame, target: pd.Series, window_size: int, todict=False):
    x = []
    y = []
    index = []

    if target is None:
        df.insert(loc=0, column="target", value=0)
        df["target"].iloc[1] = 1;
        df["target"].iloc[2] = 2
        target = pd.get_dummies(df['target'])
        df = df.drop(['target'], axis=1)
        #Por que lo hace en lo anteiror
        print("INFO To create the window_data need to create an artificial Useless Y_target  Count: ", len(df.columns), " Names : ", ",".join(df.columns))
        print("DEBUG features_W3 index Dates:: ", df.index[0], df.index[-1], " Shape: ", df.shape)
        target = target[target.index.isin(df.index)]
        df = df[df.index.isin(target.index)]

    assert len(df) == len(target)

    for i in range(window_size, len(df)+1):
        # Target is at the same row to the feature
        assert df[i - window_size: i].index[-1] == target.index[i-1]
        #Returns Multidimensional, ***3d Array*** (with time windows), for ***a*** reference GT ***N previous time rows***
        x.append(df[i - window_size: i].values) 
        if isinstance(target, pd.DataFrame): y.append(target.iloc[i-1].values)
        else: y.append(target.iloc[i-1])
        index.append(target.index[i-1])

    x = np.array(x, np.float32)
    try:
        index = np.array(index, np.datetime64)
    except Exception as ex:
        print("Exception: ", ex)
        index = np.array(index)
    y = np.array(y)

    if todict: return { 'X': x, 'y': y, 'index': index }
    else: return x, y, index
```

Example how call the method: https://github.com/Leci37/stocks-prediction-Machine-learning-RealTime-telegram/blob/master/Tutorial/RUN_buy_sell_Tutorial_3W_5min_RT.py